Hedging with SOFR futures - rolling the hedge over vs. shorting multiple contracts at once
Quick question - probably more simple but I also couldn't get a concrete answer online. If i have am planning on taking out a $1M loan in March 2025 lasting for 1 year, how would i hedge the interest rate risk with sofr futures. Specifically, would I go short 4 Mar 25 contracts, or would I roll 4 march contracts into 4 june's into 4 sep, etc, or would I short one march, june, sep, and dec together. Professor argued its shorting 4 march, but the way I see that is 9 months being unhedged; only first 3 are hedged. I also am struggling with the idea of rolling them over vs entering 4 different contracts at once. Can anyone provide insight?

I think you'd need a forward starting swap for that.

yeah, id think that id just go rec flt for 1 year against sofr and my risk is gone, but im asking partly since its a question i recieved on an exam and prof said the right thing to do was short 4 march 25s

just to be clear what are the interest payments due on your loan?

If the loan is a fixed rate loan, the rate will be fixed in Mar 2025. If you want to avoid surprises between now and then you can short 4 Mar 25 contracts so you lock in the rate that the market prices in now. This may be the reasoning behind the professor's answer. If the loan is floating rate then 4 separate contracts Mar, Jun, Sep, Dec would be my answer.
